# How to embed a SFDC portal page into website

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-service-cloud

I am currently trying to understand if it is possible to either embed SFDC portal / comunity pages or components (cases, knowledge, Ideas) into an external web site.

Have an existing public facing website that allows customers to login, from within that want to expose the cases, knowledge & chatter functionality from SFDC community into that site.

Looking for the end user experience to be seamless and avoid any popups regarding security/credentials. Ideally it as if that data was coming from our website and not SFDC.

Thinking of using the OAuth 2.0 JWT Bearer Token Flow to perform the authentication from  our website into SFDC and leverage SFDC community license.

What i am struggling with is how to then expose cases for example without having to use the API to just get a list of case records and then have to rebuild the case page UI in my own website.

All thoughts & suggestions or examples of this in action would be greatly appreciated - Thanks!

Comment: I'm a little unclear about what you are trying to accomplish. You want to embed a community page to see cases, but not use the Salesforce UI to perform the login?

Comment: Hi @AndrewMarkArmenante that is correct. We already have a "portal" on our corporate website which is vast. We are looking to add the cases / knowledge component from SFDC communities into our existing portal. Maybe use community licenses to leverage native SFDC functionality, not sure how to expose this outside of SFDC. For sure could use REST/SOAP API to make calls to SFDC, however I would then have to write the UI to show a case for example. Not sure if i could expose a VF page for example, or prebuilt SFDC components e.g. basic case UI and then just embed that in my existing portal. Thanks

Comment: Hi Eddie, did you find an answer to your question?